# Postgresql JSON keys showing with underscores between letters?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I'm currently designing a web application that talks to a Rails API on top of a Postgres DB. I'm storing some of my data in JSON format using the jsonb datatype in Postgres. The keys in the Javascript objects I'm submitting to the Rails API are in all caps:

```
{
  WEIGHT: 150,
  RACE: 'White / Caucasian',
}
```

The data submits just fine, but when I look in the database, the keys are stored with underscores between the letters, like this:

```
{
  "W_e_i_g_h_t": 150,
  "R_a_c_e": "White / Causasian",
}
```

If I use the Rails console to create a model object from the DB, the keys are still stored in the same way, with underscores between the letters. But when the data comes back to my web app, the keys are back to all caps, no underscores. What is the reason for storing the keys in the database like this?

Comment: Never seen the issue before, but the JSON you're submitting isn't valid. Is that affecting it? Valid JSON version at https://gist.github.com/maxshelley/43848eb3d699a9761cfe7b419639ec40

Comment: Postgres doesn't touch your keys. Rather rails (or one of the components, you use) transforms keys from `camelCase` to `under_scores`. But because you use all-caps keys, every letter gets an underscore.

Comment: @maxshelley Sorry, I wrote that as an actual Javascript object instead of valid JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

@pozs led me in the right direction - it looks like the resource library I'm using, [angularjs-rails-resource](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource), converts the attributes.

"By default we convert attribute names between underscore and camel case."

Thanks a lot!